# Global Package to merge several packages vhdl

Tags: vhdl, package

I have a system described in vhdl that shall run with different configurations. For that I have put the last in different packages files. I have then a global package where I uncomment the config I want to be synthesized. I use this global package every where then to declare my entities.

But the problem is that in fact while synthesizing, types and constants declared in the config packages are not visible.

I tried to declare the "use my_package.all" in the global package file above the declaration of the global package, and I tried also inside the global package.

I mean I tried:

```
use work.config1.all;
package global_package is
   ...
end global_package;
```

and I tried:

```
package global_package is
   use work.config1.all;
   ...
end global_package;
```

that is actually accepting by the synthesizer.

Does someone have a solution ? I really don't want to comment and uncomment in all my files the config I want.

Thank you!

EDIT :

For example, if I have:

file 1 :

```
package config1 is
    constant my_variable : integer := 1;
end config1;
```

file 2 :

```
package config2 is
    constant my_variable : integer := 2;
end config2;
```

file 3 :

```
use work.config1.all
-- use work.config2.all

package global is
    constant another_variable : integer := 5;
end global;
```

file 4 :

```
use work.global.all

entity my_entity is
    port(clk : in std_logic);
end my_entity ;

architecture Behavioral of my_entity is
     signal sig1, sig2 : integer;
begin
     sig1 <= another_variable;  -- I can see and use here the constant "another_variable".
     sig2 <= my_variable; -- Error ! I would like to have access here to the constant "my_variable" that the synthesizer can't see. 
end Behavioral;
```

Having then these 4 files, I can't have access to "my_variable" through only "global" package. Furthermore, I would like this constant has the value given in package config1 or config2 in function of the one that is not commented.

Comment: I don't understand your question. Please could you post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: Hey Matthew! Thanks for your interest.
I have edited the post so you can see an exemple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried a context clause declaration and a reference to it?  Here is one I have for reference:

```
context OsvvmContext is
    library OSVVM ;  
    use OSVVM.AlertLogPkg.all ; 
    use OSVVM.RandomPkg.all ;
    use OSVVM.CoveragePkg.all ;
    use OSVVM.MemoryPkg.all ;
    . . . 
end context OsvvmContext ;
```

Then in your design, you reference it:

```
library osvvm ;
  context osvvm.OsvvmContext ;
```

This way, you can edit your context clause and change the set of packages you include for your entire project.   It is VHDL-2008, so for synthesis YMMV, but for simulation, it is well supported.

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for ! Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of a easy way to make something in one package visible by using another package. (This is possible in system-verilog using `export`, but that doesn't help you.)

Instead, there are various other ways that you could solve your problem. I don't exactly know what you problem is, but here is one suggestion:

```
package global is
  constant another_variable : integer := 5;
  function set_my_variable (i : integer) return integer;
  constant my_variable : integer := set_my_variable(another_variable);
end global;

package body global is
  function set_my_variable (i : integer) return integer is
  begin
    if i = 5 then
      return 1;
    else
      return 2;
    end if;
  end function;
end package body global;

library IEEE;
use IEEE.std_logic_1164.all;
use work.global.all;

entity my_entity is
    port(clk : in std_logic);
end my_entity ;

architecture Behavioral of my_entity is
     signal sig1, sig2 : integer;
begin
     sig1 <= another_variable;  -- I can see and use here the constant "another_variable".
     sig2 <= my_variable; -- Error ! I would like to have access here to the constant "my_variable" that the synthesizer can't see. 
end Behavioral;
```

https://www.edaplayground.com/x/5xNd

Here I am initialising a constant using a function whose input is another constant. Then by simply editing that constant, I can change the value of lots of other constants. You could write various functions to initialise the various constants you wish to initialise.

Interestingly, such a function executes during elaboration. This can make debugging tricky. If you need to debug it, you can perhaps call the function to initialise a signal or variable, so that the function executes after time 0 rather than before it.

Comment: Thanks Matthew, that's an answer that I got also from a colleague.
It seems that the VHDL does not offer such a feature to see a package called through another package, isn't it?